# Angular ng-repeat resulting in NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looping through the contents of an API using ng-repeat and I'm having problems with items that have a slash in their name. For example this works:

```
    <ul ng-controller="StandingsCtrl" class="list-inline">
      <div ng-repeat="standing in standings.results">
        <li><h3>{{ standing.musher }}</h3></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

But if I were to use `{{ standing.musher/_text }}` it returns NaN. This is what the JSON looks like:

```
musher: "http://iditarod.com/race/2015/mushers/92-Mitch-Seavey/"
musher/_text: "Mitch Seavey"
position: 2
```

Is there some sort of trick to this? I'm getting no console errors at all. Using Angular 1, not 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this notation `{{ standing['musher/_text'] }}`:

```
<ul ng-controller="StandingsCtrl" class="list-inline">
  <div ng-repeat="standing in standings.results">
    <li><h3>{{ standing['musher/_text'] }}</h3></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

When using `{{ standing.musher/_text }}` Angular evaluates this as a division: `"http://iditarod.com/race/2015/mushers/92-Mitch-Seavey/" / undefined`, which results to `NaN`.